# "is that correct?"

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I used to always ask "is that correct?", here for example
[Using quotes when referring to word as word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9186/using-quotes-when-refering-to-word-as-word)

this is the old habit from stackoverflow, because they enjoy closing questions saying "not a real question".

Should I do it and are my questions safe without it?

Comment: er.. what? I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood by safe I mean it won't be closed as "not a real question", but not question will be present there.

Comment: see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/ and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/